# Dealing with resources (copying) when building a ClojurScript project using leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I have just begun playing with ClojureScript and I'd like to collect all CSS files into a single folder (`out/css`).  I found [leiningen-less](https://github.com/montoux/lein-less) and with the following config I get the compiled CSS files into the correct location:

`:less {:source-paths ["src/less"]
         :target-path "out/css"}`

I can't find any documentation on how I can handle the ordinary CSS files (e.g. the file for resetting defaults, `css/reset.css`).  Basically I want the equivalent of `cp css/*css out/css`.

I did find [lein-resource](https://github.com/m0smith/lein-resource) but it does a bit more than I require (pass things through `stencil`) and more importantly it through an `UnsupportedOperationException` on my with what I thought would a be a valid configuration:

`:resource {:resource-paths ["css" {:target-path "out/css"}]}`

Please englighten me!

Comment: Can't you pass your "regular" CSS files through Less too? That way you get everything compressed together and cut down on HTTP requests.

Comment: For lein-resource it should be
`:resource {:resource-paths [["css" {:target-path "out/css"}]]}` as resource paths are a list of either strings or a vector of [ string map].  See https://github.com/m0smith/lein-resource/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

For your particular use case just rename reset.css to reset.less. less should be able to read CSS without problems.

For more advanced frontend tooling maybe consider adding something like make/grunt/etc. More complexity but more power & flexibility.

Comment: Indeed, it's a possibility.  Didn't think of it, but now it does feel a bit like cheating.  I suppose I'll have to look into `grunt` (or something like it).  I was rather hoping that `lein` could offer a final build solution, especially with `lein cljsbuild auto`, but I guess that's not true when adding all the extra resources around the sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think better and easy solution would be that you write a function that uses clojure.java.io library functions and integrate them [with lein-less "compiler" fork](https://github.com/tangrammer/lein-less), so this is my internal function proposal:

```
(defn your-fn[] 
  (remove-folder "./out") ;; => you have to do how to make that fn following io lib doc
  (copy-folder "./css ./out") ;; ;; => you have to do how to make that fn following io lib doc
  (run-compiler  :javascript
                 {:project-root "your-project-root/"
                  :source-paths ["less"]
                  :target-path "out"})))
```

PS: note that you need to call this fn from your clojurescript compilation process, BTW I didn't know if there is a way for that :)